# Regex exactly one space in the middle

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am looking for a regex which will matches strings which contain exactly one space in the middle of the string (i.e. not at the beginning and at the end). It should allow all chars before and after the space, not only alphanumerical.

It should match:

- "a b"
- "abc 124.34"
- "hello@ world"

(If that's easier, it would be ok if it matches strings that contain one or more spaces. E.g. "a b c")

I have tried the following but this somehow does not match all cases:

```
^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: And by "in the middle" you just mean "not the beginning and not the end" right?

Comment: yes, ^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$ But this somehow does not match all cases

Comment: @silent I have updated your question to include your attempt so far. If you had included this, and the problem your effort had, you would not have got so many downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below regex to match the strings(lines) which contains exactly one space,

```
^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yM1qF4)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
[^\s]+(\s.+)\b
```

http://www.regexr.com/391po

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^.{1,} .{1,}$");
bool result = reg.IsMatch(YourStringVariable);
```